# im having trouble in while loop

Tags: java

I'm making a simple "Whack a mole" game in Java. For simplicity I have created a 10*10 box and placed 10 moles in random boxes. I want to exit the game when the user spent his 50 inputs or found all 10 moles, but there seems to be a problem in terminating the `while` loop even when the user attempts specified inputs.

Is it Instance variable scope problem? Why it is not working?

```
public class WhackAMole {

    int score = 0, molesLeft = 10, attempts;
    char[][] moleGrid = new char[10][10];
    int numAttempts, gridDimension;

    public WhackAMole(int numAttempts, int gridDimension) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.numAttempts = numAttempts;
        this.gridDimension = gridDimension;
    }

    boolean place(int x, int y) {
        return (x == 2 && y == 5) 
            || (x == 1 && y == 3) 
            || (x == 8 && y == 4) 
            || (x == 5 && y == 10) 
            || (x == 6 && y == 9) 
            || (x == 10 && y == 7) 
            || (x == 3 && y == 7) 
            || (x == 2 && y == 9) 
            || (x == 4 && y == 8) 
            || (x == 9 && y == 5);
    }

    void whack(int x, int y) {
        if (place(x, y)) {
            if (moleGrid[x - 1][y - 1] == 'W') {
                System.out.println("Already attempted! \'try other co-ordinates\' \n");
            } else {
                moleGrid[x - 1][y - 1] = 'W';
                this.score ++;
                this.molesLeft --;
            }
        }
    }

    void printGridToUser() {
        System.out.println("your score is " + score + " and " + molesLeft + " moles are left. \n");
        System.out.println("input x = -1 and y = -1 to quit the game! \n");
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
                System.out.print(" " + moleGrid[i][j] + " ");
            }

            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }

    void printGrid() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
                this.moleGrid[i][j] = '*'; 
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WhackAMole game;

        System.out.println("Lets play the Whack A Mole!\n");

        game = new WhackAMole(50, 100);
        game.printGrid();
        game.printGridToUser();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while ((game.numAttempts > 0) || (game.molesLeft > 0)) {
            System.out.println("Enter box co-ordinate\n");
            System.out.println("x co-ordinate: \n");
            int x = scanner.nextInt();

            System.out.println("y co-ordinate: \n");
            int y = scanner.nextInt();

            if (x == -1 && y == -1) {
                break;
            } else if ((x < 1 || y < 1) || (x > 10 || y > 10)) {
                System.out.println("please enter values of x and y greater than 0 and less than 11! \n");
            } else {
                game.whack(x, y);
                game.numAttempts--;
                game.gridDimension--;
                System.out.println("you can have upto " + game.numAttempts + " out of " + game.gridDimension + " boxes \n");
                game.printGridToUser();
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                if (game.place(i+1, j+1) && game.moleGrid[i][j] != 'W'){
                    game.moleGrid[i][j] = 'M';
                }
            }
        }

        game.printGridToUser();
        scanner.close();
        System.out.println("game over!!!\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `while((game.numAttempts > 0) && (game.molesLeft > 0))`?

Comment: And hint: you want us to spend our time to help you; so you please spend the 2 minutes it takes to properly indent all your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `while` loop is not ending because you are using `||` in your `while` loop. **The `||` is making your loop run until the attempts allowed i.e. 50 and the right guessing i.e. finding moles correct both are met.** So even when a gamer has finished his allowed attempts and hasn't guessed all the right moles positions, the loop will not end
**The simple solution would be to replace || with &&**

```
while ((game.numAttempts > 0) && (game.molesLeft > 0))
```

And avoid using fixed numbers i.e. 10 in your for loops instead use

```
for (int i = 0; i < game.gridDimension; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < game.gridDimension; j++) {
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is using an or for the test function. This means both condition mist be false in order for it to stop. In your case. How its written you must exhaust the numtries and have no moles left.

Change to use && vs ||.